# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd: xp_create_subdir() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.'

Tags: powershell, access-denied

I was trying to use run a powershell script, which using invoke-sqlcmd to execute my script file to backup my database into specific folder.

`Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $scriptfile -ServerInstance $ServerName -Database "Master" -Username $sqlUser -Password $sqlPassword`

It works fine in **D drive** (or other drives), but whenever on/at **C drive** and place the backup database at **C drive**, it will hit:

`Invoke-Sqlcmd: xp_create_subdir() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.'`

I wonder if I have missed out any permission grant?

The user permission (domain\ServiceAccount) was granted to **FullControl** to the output folder before invoke-sqlcmd.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I was able to perform the action after I grant the access to the folder for the account NT Service\MSSQL$Instance.